# Are there op amps or comparators that run on >100V?

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

I was using two op amps with inputs crossed as seen here:
[image]

to make inverters for stepping up voltage with high efficiency. The design works well, but op amps seem to be only built for low voltages. I am looking to make a royer converter similar to the one shown here:
[image]

Are there op amps or comparators that can run off 120 or 240 volts? If not, why?

Comment: there are. sorry i can't name you any part numbers, i've seen 150V op-amps before.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The earliest op-amps were tube circuits and could require, for example, +/- 300 V supplies. But I doubt that will help you.

Comment: Depending on what they cost, that might help me.

Comment: For an oscillator?! That's a bad mismatch of cost-effectiveness to your design. If you don't need linear behavior in your circuit (e.g. if switching behavior suffices), don't try to use a linear circuit with high voltage. Otherwise you will end up with something expensive that dissipates a lot of power.

Comment: Well, in fairness, I did ask "or comparator" which would be OK as well. I just noticed that op amps seem to be available for higher voltages than comparators, so op amps seemed to be more likely to exist given my requirements.

Comment: But why do you need a comparator? Just make an oscillator at logic levels that drives a high-voltage H-bridge.

Comment: My oscillator basically acts as an h bridge. It just seemed inefficient to have an h bridge drive an h bridge, but I guess that is just how you do it.

Comment: Wait, an oscillator can never be an H bridge, and an H bridge never oscillates by itself. An H bridge is just four switches, that can connect each one of the two nodes of a load to either one of two input nodes. See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge . An oscillator is sometimes used to turn on and off the switches of an H bridge, but they are completely different entities.

Comment: The way I look at the first picture is that you have a dual op amp that is configured to switch the power coming in through Vcc and Vee back and forth based on the voltage difference between their inputs. It is not an h bridge, but it has the same effect in that it can make current flow in one of two directions across a load by controlling a pair of switches (you obviously couple the switches in the standard h bridge so two go on when the other two go off and vica versa.)

Comment: Please specify your current requirements -- otherwise we can't answer your question. Perhaps an H-bridge like one of these would do the job for you: http://www.fairchildsemi.com/products/discrete/spm/index.html -- if I were you I would look for an H-bridge or 2 half-bridges that take logic level inputs. Then drive them with whatever digital oscillator circuit you feel like. IMHO you are not going to find an op-amp that does what you want for any reasonable price, and even if you did, it's overkill, because in that voltage range you're paying for linearity and power-handling you don't need.

Comment: 5 amps would be bare minimum. However, I know I can always use transformers to sacrifice voltage for current, so the more the better really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some op amps, like [these ones from Apex](http://www.cirrus.com/en/products/apex/index.html) that can go up to 50 A or 1200 V, but very expensive (the [PA89](http://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/PA89U_L.pdf) costs 716 USD [here](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/PA89/598-1329-ND/1761953)), and I doubt you really need them.

What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Wow, that is expensive. I doubt I need something that expensive too. I edited the question to include a link to a schematic I am currently working with. I did not want to post it because I had not marked it as answered yet, and it did not seem tasteful to link an unanswered question to another unanswered question (as it could imply I was using this question to siphon people off to my other question.)